# Update Million Rows with Foreach using WHERE with PK

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-insert

**I have the following use case:**

I have a batch file with approximately 10 million lines. Each line represents a row in my target database table but I don't if this row is to update or insert, so I have the following logic:

1. Take a line and try to make an UPDATE (always using PK), if the result is 0 (no rows affected) go to step 2.
2. Take same line, as step 1, and make an INSERT.

**Some considerations about this logic:**

1. I'm using SQL Server
2. I execute steps 1 and 2 in chunks, every 1000 lines. So, I get 1000 lines to execute step 1, and with this return, I execute step 2.
3. My table has index only in PK and UPDATE only executes using WHERE in PK.
4. UPDATE is slow 100x times than INSERT. UPDATE execute in 1hour and INSERT in 1min.
5. INSERT is executed inside a transaction, with batch insert.
6. UPDATE is not executed inside a transaction, I tried to use 1000 UPDATEs inside a transaction but I got deadlock because my application is multithreading and need to execute step 1 and 2 in parallel.

**Some things that I thought to solve this problem:**

1. Try to understand why UPDATE is so slow. But really, I don't know where to start in this case, my update seems to be correct. This is an example:

```
    UPDATE TABLEA SET ATTR1 = LINE1_ATTR1, ATTR2 = LINE2_ATTR2
    WHERE ATTR_PK1 = LINE1_ATTR_PK1 AND ATTR_PK2 = LINE1_ATTR_PK2;
```

2. Change the LOGIC: Insert all 10 million rows in a TEMP TABLE (because INSERT is faster), after doing an UPDATE FROM with ORIGINAL table and TEMP TABLE.

Comment: I think you need to give a chance to [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: My first shoot in beginning of project was use MERGE but I got a lot of deadlock error, searching in internet I found that merge have a lot of bugs and should not be used.